# Two way binding between directive/controller with watch expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular 1.0.8 -- I can't update this.

I've created a simple datepicker directive that creates three `<select>`s with date options.  This uses an isolate scope to store the selections and update the displayed days based on the month/year.  I also need to pass the *derived* date (year-month-day) back to the controller, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
app.directive("datepicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { current: "=" },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            // logic for d/m/y on scope omitted

            $scope.watch(dateHasChanged, function (newValue) {
                $scope.current = newValue;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The controller has `$scope.current = {answer: ""}`, so I'm trying to use `scope: {current: "="}` to create a binding between the directive and controller.  This is obviously not working at all.

<kbd>[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/2ju23/2/)</kbd>

---

As a bonus, the `ng-options="month.date as month.english for month in monthList"` is not working properly either.  It starts with `month.date` at 0 even though `monthList` has the first `month.date` as 1.  Could this be because of the version?

Comment: I really don't get what you did wrong... Is this plunk what you wanted or am I missing something? [PLUNK](http://jsfiddle.net/gC6KQ/1/)

Comment: You're assigning the date to `current` but you're using `current.answer` to display it in controller scope. Blame it on long day at work. ;) Btw, month.date inside the $watch does equal 1 when January is selected (at least on my computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `scope.current` object , should be updating `scope.current[property]`.

Slight bug in date calcs but [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ju23/5/)